# AWS Quicksight - Top10 offices by REVENUE divided by REVENUE

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to make a metric in Quicksight that is the ratio between TOP10 offices by REVENUE divided by REVENUE.

Thanks

The problem is that if I apply a filter to select the TOP10 offices by revenue in the numerator, the same filter is the apply to the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear from your question exactly what you meant by "ratio between TOP10 offices by REVENUE divided by REVENUE" but I have assumed you wanted the TOP N real total revenue by Store alongside the "ratio" or percent of total revenue of ALL revenue, not just the TOP N stores revenue.

To do this you can use the following calculated fields.

Make a calculated filler field to 'partition' by; that is you can use it to make a single partition of the whole data set, e.g. "single_partition_filler":

```
ifelse(isNotNull(store),1,0)
```

Make the ratio calculation you want, "Revenue over Total Revenue". The trick here is to use the "PRE_FILTER" aggregation level in the Table calculations so you are getting the sum of revenue by store PRE_FILTER divided by the sum of revenue by all stores (using the filler column) PRE_FILTER:

```
sumOver(revenue,[store],PRE_FILTER) / sumOver(revenue, [{single_partition_filler}], PRE_FILTER)
```

Make a table with "Store","Revenue (Sum)" and "Revenue over Total Revenue (Min)" and using a TOP N Filter for Store by Revenue (Sum). See Quicksight example below:
[image]

Compare with the same table unfiltered below:
[image]

Dataset used:

```
store,revenue
A,100
B,50
C,40
D,70
E,60
A,35
C,80
```